# Exclude category from site search in CS Cart

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, cs-cart

Is it possible to exclude products from specific category from search results? Cannot find any way through `fn.search.php` or through `tpl` files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hook "get_products"
Please add to files:

## app/addons/my_changes/init.php

```
<?php

if (!defined('BOOTSTRAP')) { die('Access denied'); }

fn_register_hooks(
    'get_products'
);
```

## app/addons/my_changes/func.php

```
<?php

if (!defined('BOOTSTRAP')) { die('Access denied'); }

function fn_my_changes_get_products($params, $fields, $sortings, &$condition, $join, $sorting, $group_by, $lang_code, $having){

    if (AREA=='C' && !empty($params['search_performed']) && $params['search_performed']=='Y') {
        $cids = array(...); //ex: 15, 16, 17
        $subcats = true;

        if ($subcats) {
            $_ids = db_get_fields(
                "SELECT a.category_id"."
                 FROM ?:categories as a"."
                 LEFT JOIN ?:categories as b"."
                 ON b.category_id IN (?n)"."
                 WHERE a.id_path LIKE CONCAT(b.id_path, '/%')",
                $cids
            );
            $cids = fn_array_merge($cids, $_ids, false);
        }

        $condition .= db_quote(" AND ?:categories.category_id NOT IN (?n)", $cids);
    }
}
```

you will need to populate $cids array with the category ids you wish the products to be excluded and also if also for subcategories

> $cids = array(...);

Please make sure:

- My Changes add-on is active
- If files are missing you will need to create